# How can I get a pdf to display in an object tag in safari when the "data" is a 302 redirect?

Tags: javascript, object, pdf, safari

I've got the following JSX in a react application:

```
  <object type="application/pdf" data={path} className={styles.pdfPreview} />;
```

The issue is that `path` is an endpoint on our rails app that redirects to a temporary download link. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but Safari won't show the pdf in the `<object>` tag.

Does anyone know how to either pre-fetch the pdf or just get Safari to display the pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try param tag to pass data

```
<object type="application/pdf" data={path} className={styles.pdfPreview}>
    <param name="data" value={path}>
</object>
```

Or use `<embed>` instead

```
<object data={path} type="application/pdf">
  <embed src={path} type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave that a shot but still get the same issue where it won't follow the redirect.

Comment: I confirm Safari does not follow the redirect.

Comment: Ohh I see, the follow up post by @Andrew sounds better then

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Safari just won't follow the redirect. The workaround that I settled on was to create a new endpoint on the rails server that returns a json blob with the destination url. Then, I fetch that blob from my app and use the destination url in the `<object>` tag so that there is no redirect.

It works.

Comment: You should mark it as the accepted answer